# Angularjs 1.6.6 - [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider Only in IE browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

I get below error only in IE 11 and below

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: trafficCopProvider <- trafficCop <- $http <- $templateRequest <- $route
```

in other browsers ( Chrome, Firefox, Safari, and even Microsft Edge ) no error and page load just fine. and the funny thing is no where in my project I use anything like `trafficCopProvider`. this is my app config :

```
var appRoot = angular.module('main', [
  'ngRoute',
  'ngResource',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ngStorage',
  'ngMaterial',
  'angular-flexslider',
  'angularSpinners',
  'angularLazyImg',
  'ui.filters',
  'pasvaz.bindonce'
]);

appRoot.config([
   '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$qProvider',
   function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $qProvider) {

    $qProvider.errorOnUnhandledRejections(false);
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptHttp);
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');

    $routeProvider
       .when('/', { controller: 'RootController' })
       .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
   }
]);
```

I also debug the angular core, the error occurs in this section of code when service name is `trafficCopProvider` :

```
    try {
      path.unshift(serviceName);
      cache[serviceName] = INSTANTIATING;
      cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName, caller);
      return cache[serviceName];
    } catch (err) {
      if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
        delete cache[serviceName];
      }
      throw err;
    } finally {
      path.shift();
    }
```

How this only happen in IE browsers? anyone faced to similar issue?

Comment: have you fix it?

Comment: No, still the same in IE, really out of idea :(

Comment: @Kalamarico I fixed this finally, the issue was releated to my angular material somehow, because after I get raid of all angular material that I used ( I only used for drop down menus ) the problem gone, I really not sure how but it fixed this issue in IE, however I had to use ui-select instead of md-select